# Custom camera view on iOS from HTML5

Tags: ios, html, html5-video, ios-camera

I'm building an app for iOS which I'm currently developing using web programming languages. HTML, CSS, jQuery etc. I do that because it's quicker for me to work with these languages, in a first time.

My app will give users the possibility to record a video, and I know it is possible to do that since iOS 6 with HTML5 and to upload it to my server. However, I would like to be able to create a custom camera view, for example just like the one in Snapchat, with the ability to record a custom duration for the video (for example max 20 seconds), with a progress bar etc.

My first question is : from HTML5, is it possible to limit the duration of the record of a video ? For example with maximum 20 seconds ?

Second question : is it possible for me to continue to develop my app with web languages and when the user clicks on the "record a video button", an event is fired IN the iOS code directly ? So I can launch a custom camera view in iOS language and then send it directly to my server from the iOS code ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**First question:**
No, you can't create a custom camera view in HTML. This needs to be done in Swift or Objective-C on the device.

**Second question:**
I've read, that the new `WKWebView` can recieve messages from a Javascript.
[This tutorial](http://www.joshuakehn.com/2014/10/29/using-javascript-with-wkwebview-in-ios-8.html) explains, how your app can communicate with the Javascript via delegate-calls. It requires, that your content is NOT displayed in an `UIWebView`, but in an `WKWebView` (iOS 8 or newer required)

Comment: You can also hook in javascript in `UIWebView` just not as easy as with `WKWebView`

Comment: Really interesting! I knew UIWebView, not WKWebview. Thanks for letting me know about this. The fact that it could receive message from Javascript could be very useful to me. Thank you.